# Normal scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I have the holdings section in my website:
[**eurocom**](http://eurocom.richkid.co.il/en/home/a/main/#holdingsPage), when click on part of the map, a `lightbox` open and I don't want to enable scroll in that phase.

so I put:

```
normalScrollElements:'#myModal',(light box id)
normalScrollElementTouchThreshold:0,
```

I have some questions:

1. when try to open the `lightbox`(by clicking on some map area) and then fast scroll to next section after you clicked (especially in longer then screen `lightbox`) , you can scroll, while when clicking on some map area and waiting a second after the `lightbox` is shown you cant scroll as I wish.
2. what is `normalScrollElementTouchThreshold` ?

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're using the `fullpage-js` plugin on the element `$('#fullpage').fullpage(...` but the modal has larger `z-index` than the modal block the scroll event of the `#fullpage`.
2. Please read this [What does the Fullpage.js option normalScrollElementTouchThreshold do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859082/what-does-the-fullpage-js-option-normalscrollelementtouchthreshold-do).